# If the answer being upvoted, what credit goes to the person who edits the answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, upvotes

If I'm answering the question and someone is editing the answer and giving more useful information with the original answer, what credit is going to be given to that person when the answer is being upvoted?

Comment: Upvotes go towards the answerer, not the editor? Not entirely sure what is being asked here..

Comment: for example, I'm answering some question related to python and giving least but useful information in the answer, and you as an editor of that answer given by me, are adding more information including code snippets and reference links in the same answer. which mean you should be getting some reputations for that edit right?

Comment: No, not really. And in practice, I can't think of any time it has actually happened (to a new answer). People tend to write their own answer rather than enforce their opinion in another person's answer

Comment: Not sure whether this is fair or beneficial to the site overall. This leads to more answers, instead of answers being polished and refined over time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> what credit is going to be given to that person when the answer is
>   being upvoted?

The person's name appears in the edit history of the answer, but when the answer gets upvoted, they generally speaking don't get any rep.

However if they were below 2k reputation when they made that edit and it went through a review queue then they get +2 reputation whenever that edit is accepted, capped at a life time 1000.